# Can I grow two poinsetta in one pot?

Tags: indoors

About a month ago I bought a poinsettia plant to keep in inside my home
[image: past]

After a couple of day's I found that maybe I am doing wrong care that is affecting my plant, thus went through a couple of blogs and found that I was watering it too much that is affecting it, after that doing proper care I can see new leaves are coming out of it
[image: Now]

For next one month I want to water it properly (when required) and keep it into the current place where I placed it, If still it won't work I'll move it into some east facing area where it may get morning sunlight.

I want to know as the current pot have much space left, Can I grow one more poinsettia plant into it?? If not want to know the reason??

Comment: can you or should you?

Comment: @blackthumb guess I didn't post it in english.stackExchange, And you must have rights here to edit and correct my post if you found it wrong

Comment: @Co.Aden In this case, the comment is asking for *clarification*, not judging your English. Both phrases would be fine, yet mean slightly different things. Simply editing may contradict your original question. Please accept when the community tries to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason it looks like there's a lot of room is because your Poinsettia  has lost a lot of its leaves. Beneath the soil, the roots will be taking up most of the room in your pot, so trying to squeeze another one in there isn't a good idea, there's insufficient space for both rootball/roots.

If, though, you very recently repotted your Poinsettia into its current pot, and you know the rootball isn't taking up very much room, you could risk squeezing in another one, but the likely result is both plants will fairly shortly run out of root room, and you'll have to split and repot them separately anyway.